# Probability of $d$ distinct colors when drawing from beads in $N$ colors after $K$ drawings

Tags: combinatorics

- I draw beads $k$ times.
- The beads come in $N$ different colors.
- In every draw the probably to draw a given color is always $1/N$.

How can I compute the probability of drawing d distinct colors?

For instance, if I have $N=3$ colors, and I do $k=5$ drawings. How do I compute the probability that I draw exactly $d=2$ distinct colored beads (e.g., 2 blue or 3 red, or 1 yellow and 4 blue).

**Note**: I don't care which color beads I ended up with. I don't care about the order in which the beads were drawn. All I want is probability I got d distinct colors after exactly k drawings.

Comment: It is a binomial distribution I think so let $p = \frac{1}{N} $ and use the pmf.

Comment: I could use a bit more hand holding than that if you don't mind

Comment: I posted an answer to the question that I closed this as a duplicate of to treat the general case.